# Setup SSL Kafka in k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm

I have deploy a kafka in k8s cluster .
I set up SSL using the following script:
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-platform-security-tools/blob/master/kafka-generate-ssl-automatic.sh

and then I create the k8s secrets.

My values yaml:

```
.....

  configurationOverrides:
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: ""
    metadata:
      annotations:
        service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints: "true"

  ssl:
    enabled: true
    secret_name: secrets-ssl
    keystore_key: keyStore
    keystore_key_passwd_key: keyStorePass
    keystore_passwd_key: keyPass
    truststore_key: trustStore
    truststore_passwd_key: trustStorePass
```

The pods are up and running but in the logs I see the following:

> {"type":"log", "host":"kafka-0.kafka", "level":"WARN",
> "systemid":"kafka-78640690bf244b9ba933caf199a1f336", "system":"kafka",
> "time":"2022-11-25T14:13:48.491", "timezone":"UTC",
> "log":{"message":"Controller-1001-to-broker-1002-send-thread -
> kafka.controller.RequestSendThread - [RequestSendThread
> controllerId=1001] Controller 1001's connection to broker
> **kafka-1.kafka-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 1002 rack:
> null) was unsuccessful"}} java.io.IOException: Connection to
> kafka-1.kafka-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 1002 rack:
> null) failed.**
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:70)
> at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:291)
> at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:245)
> at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
> {"type":"log", "host":"kafka-0.kafka", "level":"INFO",
> "systemid":"kafka-78640690bf244b9ba933caf199a1f336", "system":"kafka",
> "time":"2022-11-25T14:13:48.491", "timezone":"UTC",
> "log":{"message":"Controller-1001-to-broker-1002-send-thread -
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Controller id=1001,
> targetBrokerId=1002] Client requested connection close from node
> 1002"}} {"type":"log", "host":"kafka-0.kafka", "level":"INFO",
> "systemid":"kafka-78640690bf244b9ba933caf199a1f336", "system":"kafka",
> "time":"2022-11-25T14:13:48.643", "timezone":"UTC",
> "log":{"message":"Controller-1001-to-broker-1002-send-thread -
> kafka.controller.RequestSendThread - [RequestSendThread
> controllerId=1001] Controller 1001 connected to
> kafka-1.kafka-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 1002 rack:
> null) for sending state change requests"}}

Seems that is unable to connect to kafka-1.kafka-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local
I have set two replicas.
Any idea?

Comment: Please show your broker advertised listeners and headless service definition. Or, have you tried using Strimzi? Confluent Helm Charts are not supported

Comment: I am using the incubator kafka helm chart

Comment: [That is not maintained, or is deprecated](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/kafka#%EF%B8%8F-repo-archive-notice). Please try Strimzi

Comment: I am using the incubator because this helm chart exists in my company registry and we are not able to use from another registry.

Comment: Strimzi is not a Chart. It's an Operator. I'd strongly recommend not using something that's no longer supported or maintained.